# Make hive returns the value only

Tags: hive

I want to make hive only returns the value only! not other words like information about the processing!

```
hive> select max(temp) from temp where dtime like '2014-07%' ;
Query ID = hduser_20170608003255_d35b8a43-8cc5-4662-89ce-9ee5f87d3ba0
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1496864651740_0008, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1496864651740_0008/
Kill Command = /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1496864651740_0008
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2017-06-08 00:33:01,955 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-06-08 00:33:08,187 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.13 sec
2017-06-08 00:33:14,414 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 5.91 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 5 seconds 910 msec
Ended Job = job_1496864651740_0008
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 5.91 sec   HDFS Read: 853158 HDFS Write: 5 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 5 seconds 910 msec
OK
44.4
Time taken: 20.01 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

I want it to return  the value only which is  44.4

Thanks in advance...

Comment: First step: learn about `stdout` / `stderr` for command-line utilities. Second step: learn about how the Linux shell enables to redirect `stderr` from a specific command, into "nothing". The next step might be about filtering `stdout` with regular expressions (RegEx) but that would require some basic computing skills...

Answer (score 0):

You can put result into variable in a shell script. max_temp variable will contain the result only:

```
max_temp=$(hive -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; select max(temp) from temp where dtime like '2014-07%';")

echo "$max_temp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use -S

```
hive -S -e  "select max(temp) from temp where dtime like '2014-07%';"
```

Comment: @user3446106 : please make the answer as correct if it works for you